# Is it possible to extend Sublime Text 3's go_to_definition?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

This will unfortunately be a broad question.

go_to_definition:

1. doesn't work for jinja2 macros
2. doesn't go to variable declarations
3. I also want it to add a suffix and search for that phrase too

Is it possible to improve the go_to_definition so I can make it work for the above scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of fact, it is possible, if you know Python. The `GotoDefinition` class is defined in the Default package in `symbol.py` (for some reason...). To access it in ST3, install the [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) via Package Control. Open the Command Palette, search for the `PackageResourceViewer: Edit Package Resource` option, scroll down to `Default`, then scroll down and select `symbol.py`. You can now edit to your heart's delight, and assuming everything goes properly, once you save the file the plugin should be automatically reloaded and you can test your modifications.

In case you're not that familiar with developing Sublime plugins, here is the [API reference](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html), the [unofficial docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info), and the [Sublime forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum) for your perusal. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, sounds good, I'm guessing the modification would get overwritten after a sublime text update? (that seems to never happen tho)

Comment: @KaanSoral it would, so just keep a backup in your Users folder or something, and the next time Jon Skinner feels like releasing a new feature we didn't ask for, you can just overwrite the file again.